# How to set terminal title for Centos 8 WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, centos, title-bar

I can install `xtitle` on Ubuntu WSL, however, this package is not available on CentOS WSL (possibly also CentOS itself).

Install `xtitle` on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install xtitle -y
```

These commands won't install `xtitle` on CentOS:

```
sudo yum install xtitle -y
sudo dnf install xtitle -y
```

Any work-arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'xtitle' program only outputs [these "escape sequences"](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html), so it can be replaced with 'echo -e' or 'printf' or similar functions in any programming language:

```
printf '\e]0;%s\e\\' "My title here"
```

(The closing sequence can be either `\e\\` (ESC \) or `\a` (BEL); the former is more correct but the latter is more widespread, although most terminals support both.)

Answer (score 1):

`printf` or `echo -e` to set terminal title won't work if `PS1` (prompt for shell 1) is set.

The following command set text in title bar and also prompt:

```
export PS1="\e]0;TITLE\a\u@\h:\w\n$ "
```

The title bar is set as 'TITLE' and prompt shows up as, for example:

```
user@server:\some\path
$ _
```

Put this function `xtitle` in .bashrc or /etc/profile:

```
#The '\e]0;$1\a' is to make the title in title bar
#The rest is the prompt
function xtitle {
  export PS1="\e]0;$1\a\n\u@\h:\w\n\$ ";
}
```